# Where to keep backend reusable script in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a js file in my Nodejs which is not a middleware. It will store a function that will receive value and output a result using module exports. I wanted to know what would be an appropriate place to have this file on.

I cannot keep it in the middleware folder because it is not a middleware. I cannot keep it inside the public folder where because I only keep my front end scripts. I also do not want to keep it in my routes folder

Comment: My personal structure is to have a `lib` folder for all libraries - for indeed they are libraries. This comes from the unix tradition. I even put my middlewares in `lib` because middlewares are nothing but libraries - for example you load both the `cors` middleware and `moment` library from `npm`. You don't get `cors` form a special `middleware.npm` repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your current file structure and standards, where one keeps backend scripts.

I would have put it inside a folder `src/internals` or `src/scripts` along with other scripts used for that particular project.